# How can ı get CSS Folder when ı run sass live compiler of VSCode?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass

I am using the Sass Live Compiler feature of VSCode. In some of the videos I watched, I saw that people automatically created a css folder after clicking the "Watch Sass" button. I do not have such a feature. I need to keep Sass and CSS in the same folder. How can I set this status to be in two separate folders? it is like this now [image] When ı move it's to other folder's Sass Live Compiler Doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to settings (ctrl+,) and search for *live sass compile settings*.
then click on *Edit in settings.json* there you can specify the `savePath`.

[image]

I've set it to be in the main folder `./` but you can set it to `./newfolder`

[image]

### caution:

**you should have specified the right path in your HTML file in order for the CSS to take effect.**